# How to sign message body with RSASSA-PSS in mimekit?

Tags: c#, mimekit

I am using Mimekit with .NET Core 2.2. I am trying to sign a message with RSASSA-PSS and cannot find a way to set the signing algorithm for the RSASignaturePadding. Changing the DigestAlgorithm results in the wrong padding to be used.

How can I fix this code snippet to sign with RSASSA-PSS instead of default for padding?

```
    public MimeMessage SignMessage(MimeMessage message, MailboxAddress address)
    {
        CryptographyContext.Register(typeof(WindowsSecureMimeContext));

        using (var ctx = new WindowsSecureMimeContext(StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
        {
            X509Certificate2 cert = null;
            string thumbprint = "<myThumbprint>";
            var machineStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            machineStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection machineCerts = machineStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
            if (machineCerts.Count == 1)
            {
                cert = machineCerts[0];
            }

            if (cert != null)
            {

                CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(cert)
                {
                    DigestAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithm.Sha256
                };


                message.Body = MultipartSigned.Create(ctx, signer, message.Body);
            }
        }

        return message;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible to do in MimeKit and it seems that the SignedCms class does not have any way to specify the PSS padding mode unless it is a property on the private key of the X509Certificate2?

Update:

I've done a bit more research and I figured out how to support this using BouncyCastle so I've just added a `CmsSigner.RsaSignaturePaddingScheme` property that will allow you to specify `RsaSignaturePaddingScheme.Pss`.

This *only* works when using a BouncyCastle-based SecureMimeContext, however, so what you can do is this:

```
public MimeMessage SignMessage(MimeMessage message, MailboxAddress address)
{
    using (var ctx = new TemporarySecureMimeContext ())
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = null;
        string thumbprint = "<myThumbprint>";
        var machineStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
        machineStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        X509Certificate2Collection machineCerts = machineStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
        if (machineCerts.Count == 1)
        {
            cert = machineCerts[0];
        }

        if (cert != null)
        {
            CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(cert)
            {
                RsaSignaturePaddingScheme = RsaSignaturePaddingScheme.Pss,
                DigestAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithm.Sha256
            };


            message.Body = MultipartSigned.Create(ctx, signer, message.Body);
        }
    }

    return message;
}
```

To start using this feature *today* (I have not yet made a public release), you can go to https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit and grab the latest MyGet build (which is a CI-generated nuget package).